# Find the assembly name of a process who's file has been renamed

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a file, `MyProcess.exe`.
I run it, and then while it is still running, rename it to `old_MyProcess.exe`.

I'm going over all of the process with the `MyProcess.exe` name, find it but `process.Modules[0].FileName` returns `MyProcess.exe` and not `old_MyProcess`.

I noticed that in Task Manager, if you add the 'Image path name' column you can see the `old_MyProcess.exe`, but both the win32 calls `GetModuleFileNameEx` and `GetImagePathName` returned `MyProcess.exe`.

Comment: What do you mean? I am able to rename it while it is working, yes. And it is generally possible.

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect undocumented magic.

Comment: I'm guessing you assign the magic to the Task Manager's ability to show the original file name?

Comment: I would only know of two ways to implement this sort of magic: `1` Monitoring files in the target directory using e.g. [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417.aspx) (may miss certain notifications). `2` Storing the executable image's file ID (see [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363788.aspx)) and subsequently opening it with [OpenFileById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432.aspx) to query for its file name.

Comment: @IInspectable: I was thinking along similar lines but both require task manager to be running before the file is renamed, and it doesn't need to be. You can rename the .exe and then run task manager and it still knows the new name.

Comment: @HansPassant, you got it right. Answer so I can mark as solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around Taskmgr.exe with Dumpbin.exe /imports to see what winapi functions it uses, I see a good match in [QueryFullProcessImageName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Windows v6.0 and up required (Vista or later).

Turns out that guess was correct :)