# Get-Process cannot get the latest path

Tags: powershell

considering the following scenario:

1. I run the executable on the server
2. I renamed the executable files to a different one while the process is still running.
3. then use get-process -ID 50620 | Select * to list detail information of this specific process

the path shows previous data, while the actual executable file name was changed already...

how can I get the latest file name from the PowerShell?

Thanks!

why i am asking this:

we are using Terminal server for PDA applications, so once we updated the executable on server, we modify the pervious executable name to different one so when RDP users login system will automatically load the new executable.

just trying to get those sessions running pervious executable(who doesn`t logout and login again since the update) to send message so they know the executable was updated and they have so logout and login soon to load the latest code.

Comment: When you run an executable, then it is loaded (copied) into the RAM. The mentioned path has only "historical" value and will not be updated. Imagine you would copy the executable, what path would then be your desired path?

Comment: Thank you for the comment Tomas, but I can actually get the real-time executable name from the task manager if I right-click the process in the details tab of task manager and looking for a properties, it will pop-up a properties window of executable and shows the current executable name.  just wondering if i can get the name from the powershell?

Comment: @JohnnyBao Per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141045) taskmgr uses `QueryFullProcessImageName`, with the caveat that  it's only available in Vista+.

Comment: @dxiv you got this!  Thanks! :D